# HTML5 video tag, playing video from url but not locally

Tags: html5-video

Ok, I read this [blogpost](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/#comment-80315) and tried to play the video on my Iphones safari browser. It works when the video src of the video points to the videos online url:

http://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.m4v

But as soon as I try to play it from the local dir it does not work!!

```
<video id="video" autobuffer height="240" width="360">
    <source src="http://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.m4v" />
</video>

<video id="video" autobuffer height="240" width="360">
    <source src="media/video/BigBuck.m4v" />
</video>
```

I mean its the same video, I downloaded it! It works on both occasions on my computers browser.

Why in the world would this happen?

[image]

Comment: Hm, you sure that `media` is a subdir of the dir the html sits in?

Comment: Yes. it works on my browser. its the same than all my other media, css, js, images etc.

Comment: Even if I paste the exact link to the video in my phones browser it wont play

Comment: Can you replicate this ?

Comment: Me? I'm sorry, I don't have an iPhone. What I asked was the only thing I could think of; I have no further suggestions. By the way, the blog you linked to is for Android.

Comment: I know, im actually teting for Android. But it was easier testing this on my iphone. But it also does not work on my android 4.0.4 device.

Comment: What is the URL of the html file that's referencing the video?